# WordPress I cannot receive emails sent from forms to my own domain.

Tags: php, wordpress, email, cpanel, whm

I am using a plugin called Form Manager on a WordPress site to manage form submissions. I had the site setup on a VPS that was running Plesk and I never had any issues. I recently moved the site to a VPS running WHM/cPanel and I am now unable to receive emails sent to the same domain as the site.

Remote Mail Exchanger is the selected option for the domain under the MX Record options in cPanel. Other sites on the same server are able to receive emails at their domains. They use different methods and different plugins though. I tried adding the clients MX records and no difference was made (I still used remote mail exchanger).

[image]

I have the option in the plugin to use WordPress (wp_mail) or PHP (mail). Neither option makes a difference.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your server is seeing itself as a mail server for your domain, meaning it's not even going to DNS to look for MX records. I see this a lot with Plesk and it's probably common to cPanel as well.

What you will likely have to do is [disable local delivery in Sendmail](https://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail)

Comment: This is what I think is happening as well. I do not have anything at /etc/mail/sendmail.mc my mail directory is empty except for a directory called spamasassin ...do I need to install sendmail?

Comment: No. Look at your php.ini file and find out what `mail` calls to send mail. If sendmail isn't installed you probably have Postfix instead.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you using free host services. These hosts are not support the mail services. You can send emails using php function (mail())

Comment: At the end of the day, Wordpress is simply writing its own wrapper for `mail()`